# Default-zoom-setting for pdf-files in google-chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, pdf, google-chrome-extensions

I use google-chrome as my default application for pdf-files. The problem that I have is, that the default-zoom of 100% is automaticaly applied (I would like 150% zoom) when I open a pdf document, which bothers me alot. I tried the following things already:

1. go into settings and change the default zoom-level
2. go into settings and change the default zoom-level for a specific site
3. change the zoom-settings with tampermonkey (Chrom-extension)
4. Chrome-extension "Zoom for Google Chrome"

Why they  couldnt solve the problem:

1. This solves the issue, but it also zooms in on every other side and makes google-chrome unusable for me
2. This works well for web-pages but it can not be applied to pdf-files
3. Tampermonkey doesn't seem to work on chromes pdf-viewer and I am also not capable to extract any information from these sites with the browser-console
4. Also doesn't work on these pages

The reason why I need to use the google-chrome to view my pdf-files is, that I use one-drive everyday for my studies and the links to the pdf-files are for the browser only.

Comment: So far it seems to be impossible: [https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/10378560/hi-how-can-i-change-the-default-zoom-level-of-google-chrome-by-group-policy-is-there-any-option?hl=en](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/thread/10378560/hi-how-can-i-change-the-default-zoom-level-of-google-chrome-by-group-policy-is-there-any-option?hl=en)

Answer (score 6):

`#zoom=150` parameters solves this problem for web-links.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which partially solves the problem. If you visit websites with a typical url (I personally use it for scientific publications), you can install a chrome extension like [URL Auto Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-auto-redirector/mckfcfnegaimgcgepikhdnajpkkhdnkn/related) and add the `#zoom=150` automatically.

In my case it is something like `https://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.114.036601` (you might not be able to open this page), i.e., domain + /pdf/ + other stuff.

In `URL Auto Redirector` I then created the rule

```
Source:        (.*?)pdf(.*?)(?<!#zoom=\d\d\d)$
Destination:   $1pdf$2#zoom=200
```

which works like a charm.

If you are unfamiliar with `regex` (and still interested in this problem) feel free to comment the structure of the websites important for you and I try to find a more general solution.

This will also match some websites that are not pdfs (e.g. this post :)) but the `zoom` argument is not changing anything. Also, I deleted all the other rules in the `URL Auto Redirector`-extension.

Comment: Works fine for me. Thanks for the comment :)